# Error 1004 with Excel-VBA trying to set hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to do a very simple thing like this:

```
Sub HyperAdd()

    'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink

    For Each xCell In Selection
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

The routine fails on very large sheets, when used beyond a certain cell, with a '1004' "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Just select a cell range and hit the button. In this case the hyperlink converter button works as expected up to cell D5962, but fails further down. I see no obvious difference between the "good" and the "bad" cell blocks. Needless to say, this thing is totally baffling me.

Comment: I understand that your loop runs through a large range till it hits a certain cell that triggers the error, right? Could you try to set a breakpoint at the line starting with `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks...` and see what is the value of `xCell.Formula`? (it may be worth setting some `IF` such that you will not need to go through 5000 breakpoints till you reach the problematic cell).

Comment: Excel has a maximum of [66,530 hyperlinks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f) in a Worksheet. Is it possible you're hitting the limit?

Comment: Thanks Comintern, you've hit the nail on the head :)